# Is localStorage still readable after an App transfer in the Apple developer program?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, local-storage, iphone-developer-program

I have successfully received a transferred app as per Apple's documentation on transfers: [App transfers.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

Is data that was written to localStorage in the previous version of the app pre-transfer still available for reading by the new version of the app post-transfer?

The pre-transfer version of the app (eg v1.1.0) wrote something to localStorage:

```
localStorage.set("user_id", 1);
```

And now the post-transfer version (eg v1.2.0) is trying to read that value from localStorage:

```
var userId = localStorage.get("user_id");
```

But it is returning nothing (either null or undefined).  Is there a known problem where an app post-transfer cannot read localStorage set by an app pre-transfer?

I know that localStorage can be deleted at will by iOS ([usually only happens if the disk storage is full](https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/64)), but this problem is happening for everyone who installs the new version, so I am fairly certain that is not the cause of the problem here.

I also know that access to localStorage is controlled by the [same-origin-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy): read/write access is granted only if the scheme, host and port are the same.  In my app the scheme, host and port have not changed: this is from my cordova config.xml

```
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*"/>
```

And this was also the setting used for the pre-transfer release.

Why is the post-transfer version of the app not able to read the localStorage? What can I do to fix this?

Both versions were released through itunes connect and downloaded to the iphone from the app store.

If I install the post-transfer dev version, then make a new build and upgrade to that it can read localstorage. If I install the post-transfer dev version on my iphone, and then update it with the post-transfer live app store version, it can read the localstorage.  So it does work when upgraded from post-transfer version to a later post-transfer version.